# PHP7: Methods with a scalar type declaration refuse to type juggle NULL values, even in weak/coercive mode

Tags: php, casting, php-7, type-hinting

As of [PHP 7.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php), the scalar type hints `int`, `float`, `string`, and `bool` can be included in method signatures.  By default, these type declarations operate in weak/coercive mode (or "[type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)" mode).  According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration):

> PHP will coerce values of the wrong type into the expected scalar type if possible. For example, a function that is given an integer for a parameter that expects a string will get a variable of type string.

But even though it is possible to coerce NULL into the integer 0, a method with an `int` typehint will **refuse** to coerce an inbound value of `NULL` to the integer 0.

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public function test(int $arg)
    {
        echo $arg;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->test('123'); // 123
$obj->test(false); // 0
$obj->test(null);  // TypeError: Argument 1 passed to MyClass::test()
                   // must be of the type integer, null given
```

And similarly, even though [it is possible](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) to coerce NULL into the boolean `false`, a method with a `bool` typehint will **refuse** to coerce an inbound value of `NULL` to the boolean `false`.  The same goes for the `float` and `string` type hints as well.

This behavior seems to contradict the documentation on php.net.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently *no way* to allow a method with a scalar type hint to automatically **type juggle** inbound NULL values to the declared type.

Per the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5#behaviour_of_weak_type_checks) responsible for introducing this feature into PHP 7:

> The weak type checking rules for the new scalar type declarations are **mostly** (emphasis added) the same as those of extension and built-in PHP functions. The only exception to this is the handling of NULL: in order to be consistent with our existing type declarations for classes, callables and arrays, NULL is not accepted by default, unless it is a parameter and is explicitly given a default value of NULL.

However, NULL values can be accepted as NULLs in the following scenarios:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    // PHP 7.0+
    public function testA(int $arg = null)
    {
        if (null === $arg) {
            echo 'The argument is NULL!';
        }
    }

    // PHP 7.1+
    // https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types
    public function testB(?int $arg)
    {
        if (null === $arg) {
            echo 'The argument is NULL!';
        }
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->testA(null); // The argument is NULL!
$obj->testB(null); // The argument is NULL!
```